# Reduce transpiled code helpers with babel and webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, babeljs

In my project, I'm using [babel](http://babeljs.io/) to transpile down to ES5. I'm using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to bundle everything together. There are several places where babel adds a function at the top of any given file to support some feature (like rest params [here](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/dist/formly.js#L134) or `import` statements [here](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/dist/formly.js#L179)).

For example, pretty much every file has this at the top:

```
var _interopRequire = function (obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj["default"] : obj; };
```

And several files have this:

```
var _toConsumableArray = function (arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) arr2[i] = arr[i]; return arr2; } else { return Array.from(arr); } };
```

In my [smaller project](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly) this isn't a huge deal, but in my project at work, I'm doing the same thing and I'm sure I could shave more than a few bytes by figuring out a way to just have all of these polyfills in one place and have babel/webpack reference those. So rather than having `_interopRequire` in every file that's using `import` (which is almost every file), have it in one place and be referenced.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what to do about a library or small project. I'm thinking you wouldn't really get any benefit from using the external helpers. However, for my application, I found that after gzipping, it's actually smaller than if I include the helpers.

> Babel has a few helper functions that'll be placed at the top of the generated code if needed so it's not inlined multiple times throughout that file. This may become an issue if you have multiple files, especially when you're sending them to the browser. **gzip alleviates most of this concern but it's still not ideal.**

(emphasis added)

So that's my solution and I'm happy with that. (Basically, don't worry about it).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question some time ago, and there is clear answer in documentation:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime

In webpack config you can do it just as 'babel?optional=runtime'

Comment: Awesome, I think this is exactly what I need. However, when I do this, my `dist` file gets bloated with all of `core-js`. Is there any way to configure webpack to remove modules that are not used in my own code?

Comment: Also, it's not just `core`. It's also `helpers` as well.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this is what are you looking for: https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/external-helpers/ (personally I have not tryed it since I am using core-js, and maybe most of helpers)

Comment: I'll look into that, but that wouldn't help me with `core` :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use [Babel Runtime](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/user-handbook.md#toc-babel-runtime),

> Since these helpers can get pretty long, and they get added to the top of every file you can move them into a single "runtime" which gets required.
>
> Start by installing babel-plugin-transform-runtime and babel-runtime:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
$ npm install --save babel-runtime
```